# How to update the HEAD branch in a mirrored clone?

Tags: git, github

I have a local repository which I cloned through `git clone --mirror <ssh-url>`. I then keep it up to date using `git remote update --prune`.

At this point, `HEAD` points to `refs/heads/master`

I then go to the Admin section of my github repository, and change the default branch. All of my branches are updated as normally, but HEAD is still `refs/heads/master` (yes, the branches have different hashes)

My current thought is to use `git ls-remote` to get the hash of HEAD and all branches, then with some grep/awk magic, extract the hash of HEAD and then choose the first branch with a matching hash, and use `git symbolic-ref HEAD <found branch name>` to set it locally.

But is there a simpler way to get the remote `HEAD` branch name (in a manner that it can be updated in a script)?

Comment: If it matters/helps, I'm on git version 1.8.1.4 installed on Mountain Lion from homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a command for this:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

From `git help remote`:

> With -a, the remote is queried to determine its HEAD, then the
> symbolic-ref refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD is set to the same branch. e.g.,
> if the remote
> HEAD is pointed at next, "git remote set-head origin -a" will set the symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD to
> refs/remotes/origin/next. This will
> only work if refs/remotes/origin/next already exists; if not it must be fetched first.

Comment: The problem is that we're working with a mirrored clone therefore there are no remote tracking branches (local branches and tags are made for each remote branch and tag) and this command errors out with `error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/new-master` Also interesting that it seems to use SHA to determine the remote HEAD since if there are multiple branches on the remote pointing to the HEAD revision, we get instead `error: Multiple remote HEAD branches. Please choose one explicitly with: <list of branches>`

Comment: You could just add a remote for this. Git will only guess the remote HEAD if you are using a protocol that requires this. Unfortunately I don’t know which protocols this are.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simpler way to get the remote HEAD branch name

```
git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD
```

and you can use a url or path directly instead of the remote name, you can do e.g. `git ls-remote --symref . HEAD` to get the local checkout in a rather spectacularly roundabout way.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using ssh, you can use this command if you have proper ssh access:

```
scp yourusername@yourserver:/path/to/the/server/repo/HEAD local/repo/.git/HEAD
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The remote in this case is a Github Enterprise instance. But even against public github you wind up with: `Invalid command: 'scp -f -- org/repoName.git/HEAD'` and a message about using ssh to clone `git://` url.

Comment: I said “if you have proper ssh access” – you don’t have proper ssh access on github.

Answer (score -1):

To query the remote HEAD, use

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git://...
  Push  URL: git://...
  HEAD branch: whateverremotehead
  Remote branches:
    ...
```

and parse the output, looking for "HEAD branch", and use that in

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/whateverremotehead
```

I'm not aware of any nicer way.